# Perfect infinitive for future

Tags: grammar

Can I use perfect infinitive for future plans?

For instance: It will be fun to have travelled with you during next week.

Is it grammatically correct?

Comment: It's "grammatical", but what good does knowing that do you? There are almost no circumstances in which a native speaker would find it idiomatically acceptable. In fact, it's such a weird thing to say that even if you *could* contrive a context where you really did want the exact meanings implied by the choice of tenses, you would never use those words to express yourself.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Would it be _appropriate_ in a situation where a character has an inner monologue about his recently deceased relative, whilst strapping himself to a time machine and planning to undo his wrongdoings? "you would never use those words(...)" is "during" the problem here, could you elaborate?

Comment: The temporal flux capacitor effect! _It will have been fun to travel with you last week!_

Comment: @FumbleFingers, very respectfully I would like to tell that there is a lot of difference between native and non native speakers. I am not a native speaker when I use dictionary or grammar books, with every word and tense it is not written what is acceptable for native speakers. I see only one thing that is the "usage" of words and tenses. Regards

Comment: @P.E Dant I think this question is not a duplicate, I am specifically asking about perfect infinitive with reference to "future". Thanks

Comment: I agree with @Amn The supposed duplicated question does not mention the use of the perfect infinitive to refer to future time.

Comment: @Amn: But I assume you understand the basic meaning of "perfect" verb forms, so you can see the difference between your perfect infinitive *to have traveled* and the simple infinitive *to travel*. Your example is saying that *to be in the state of having traveled* will be fun, whereas the more normal simple infinitive says *the actual act of traveling* will be fun, which would nearly always be what you meant. Both meanings *can* be grammatically expressed (as I said, your example is "valid"), but why would you speak about the fun of *having done* something rather than the fun of *doing* it?